# Excem macro - sum ordered quantity dynamically

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a macro for one of my daily processes to sum the ordered quantities of some orders on the TOTAL column.
The problem is that each day the number of orders differ.
SO I have to find the TOTAL column and sum the values of the oders from the left.

The file looks like this:

Group   Code    Ord1    Ord2    Ord3    Ord4    Ord5    Ord6    Ord7    TOTAL

101 68070   0   0   0   6   0   0   0

I managed to find the TOTAL cell and to potion under it but I don't know how to proceed further to sum the values on the left.

Sub Find()

```
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = "TOTAL"
If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    With Sheets("Data").Range("A1:AN1")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

How can I dynamically sum the values from Ord1..Ordx on the TOTAL column?

I need to mention that on the right of column TOTAL there are others columns with formulas, so, I have to find the TOTAL not just sum all cells from C2 to the right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to sum each row? Or are you looking for a total of all orders for the whole column? Also, will Ord1 always be column C?

Comment: I need to sum each row. And, yes, the first orders is always on column C.

Answer (score 1):

Because I received an answer to my question on another website, I thought is ok to post it also here maybe will help someone at some point.

"Your question is a little unclear. I infer that you will have multiple rows of Group/Codes with a varying number of orders in the Ord1:Ordx columns for each group/code. Then, you wish to total each group/code's orders in the Total column. I assume that your active columns are A:AN for orders and AO for the Total. Is all of this correct?

Edit: Based on your confirmation of my inferences, try the following event handler.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
 Dim i, LastRow 
 LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
 On Error GoTo errhandler 
 Application.EnableEvents = False 
 For i = 2 To LastRow 
 Cells(i, "AO").Value = Application.Sum(Range("C" & i & ":" & "AN" & i)) 
 If Cells(i, "AO").Value = 0 Then 
 Cells(i, "AO").Value = "" 
 End If 
 Next i 
 errhandler: 
 Application.EnableEvents = True 
 End Sub
```

Select the worksheet containing your order recap and right click the sheet tab at the bottom.

Select 'View Code'

Paste the event handler into the white editing area to the right (right click inside the area and 'Paste').

Close the VBE.

Upon any/every change of data in the worksheet (add/delete/modify), column AO will return the totals of the orders listed in columns C:AN. This assumes row 1 contains headers, as you indicate in your question.

Note: any row where there are no orders entered, the value in column AO will be returned as 'blank' to avoid having a possible boatload of '0' entries cluttering up the view.... "

Thanks to garbo7441.